# Mulitple tables join in Hive getting error - Both left and right aliases encountered in join

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to join 3 tables. Following are the table details.

[image]

**I am expecting following results**

[image]

Here is my query and getting error as "**both left and right aliases encountered in join 'id'**".
This was due to joining 3rd table with 1st and 2nd table(last full join statement).

```
select coalesce(a.id,b.id,c.id) as id,
ref1,ref2,ref3
from v_cmo_test1 a 
FULL JOIN v_cmo_test2 b on (a.id = b.id)
FULL JOIN v_cmo_test3 c on (c.id in (a.id,b.id))
```

If I am using below query, id 3 is repeating in the table which I don't want.

```
select coalesce(a.id,b.id,c.id) as id,
ref1,ref2,ref3
from v_cmo_test1 a 
FULL JOIN v_cmo_test2 b on a.id = b.id
FULL JOIN v_cmo_test3 c on c.id = a.id
```

[image]

Could any one help me on how to achieve the expected results and really appreciate for your help.

Thanks, Babu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very tricky requirement. data is incorrect because you are using test1 as driver, outer joins arent working properly. And this can occur with other tables. So, i am joining two tables at a time to achieve what you want.

```
select coalesce(inner_sq.id,c.id) as id,ref1,ref2,ref3
from 
(select coalesce(a.id,b.id,c.id) as id,ref1,ref2
from v_cmo_test1 a 
FULL JOIN v_cmo_test2 b on a.id = b.id
) inner_sq
FULL JOIN v_cmo_test3 c on c.id = inner_sq.id
```

Inner_sq query output -

```
1,bab,kim
2,xxx,yyy
3,,mmm
```

When you full join above with test3, you should get your output.